# Reading large CSV file on a JavaScript frontend application

Tags: javascript, csv, parquet, parquetjs

I have several CSV files that I'd like to use in a JavaScript based front-end application. Most of them are stored on a Cloud. Considering the fact that some of the CSV are sometimes very big (several gigabytes), I first considered using [parquetjs](https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs) for compression, and transfer them to the front-end as small parquet files (we have large redundancy in our CSV files and parquet allows us to achieve high compression results, ie a 1.6Gb CSV file is compressed as a 7Mb parquet file).

For optimization issues, I intended to use the stream capabilities of parquetjs to extract the CSV files "on the fly". But somehow this feature doesn't seem to be very mature yet. I wanted to know if it was possible to find another solution in order to have fast streamed CSV decompression. Are there zip-based JavaScript packages that would do the trick ? Transfering and reading big CSV files directly doesn't seem to be an optimal solution for me.

Comment: I actually have a hard time to think of a common system which would be able to treat such big CSV files in a performant way

Comment: Who is going to be using this app?  There is no human that can deal with gigabytes of information on a page.  I think you need to re-think the design, maybe using the fetch idea and an api that has pagination.

Comment: @abbaf33f we are currently optimizing our backend in order to reduce the CSV files. In fact we won't be needing all the CSV data in the front. Only a few columns for visualization. We thought about using apache-arrow in order to have a Pandas-like behavior for our needs, but that solution proved to be defective

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, and depending on what you want to do on the client, you could potentially use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and use the `response.body` stream to process as it’s still downloading.

There’s [a post by Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/#streams) which touches on how to read in a stream of CSV data, which could be useful.